# What Event Handler to Subscribe and Assert.AreEqual Fails

Tags: nunit

I want to invoke a method when my integration test fails (i.e., `Assert.AreEqual` fails), is there any event delegate that I can subscribe to in NUnit framework? Of course the event delegate must be fired when the tests fail.

This is because in my tests there are a lot of `Assert` statement, and I can't tell need to log the `Assert`, along with the assertion information that cause a problem in my bug tracker. The best way to do this is to when the test fails, a delegate method is invoke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no event I can subscribe to in case of assert fail

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious, what problem are you trying to solve by doing this? I don't know of a way to do this with NUnit, but there is a messy way to do it. You can supply a Func and invoke it as the fail message. The body of the Func can provide you delegation you're looking for.

```
var callback = new Func<string>(() => {
        // do something
        return "Reason this test failed";
    });
Assert.AreEqual("", " ", callback.Invoke());
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are wanting to create your own test-runner.

There is a distinction between tests (a defines the actions) and the running of the tests (actually running the tests). In this case, if you want to detect that a test failed, you would have to do this when the test is run.

If all you are looking to do is send an email on fail, it may be easiest to create a script (powershell/batch) that runs the command line runner, and sends an email on fail (to your bug tracking system?)

If you want more complex interactivity, you may need to consider creating a custom runner. The runner can run the test and then take action based on results. In this case you should look in the `Nunit.Core` namespace for the test runner interface.

For example (untested):

```
TestPackage package = new TestPackage();
package.add("c:\some\path\to.dll");
SimpleTestRunner runner = new SimpleTestRunner();
if (runner.Load(Package)){
    var results = runner.Run(new NullListener(), TestFilter.Empty, false, LoggingThreshold.Off);
    if(results.ResultState != ResultState.Success){
        ... do something interesting ...
    }
}
```

EDIT: better snippet of code https://stackoverflow.com/a/5241900/1961413