# Host Unit Testing Framework in our Application? (Nunit, xUnit, MsTest)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, xunit.net

We are developing and maintaining a legacy winforms application. The application uses a domain model which ist quite separate from the GUI layer, but because of many dependecies, it is hard to unit test. At least we have a build and an installation script which we can use to automatically build and deploy the application.

Now if we could only have some automated system tests...

We came up with the following idea:

First, we could write our tests in script files like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public void TestSaveACustomer()
    {
        var c = new Customer();
        c.Name="Miller";
        Mapper.Save(c);
        Assert.IsTrue(c.CustomerId >0);
    }
}
```

Then, after building and deploying the application, we could run the scripts with a script runner that is baked into our application binary. We imagine we could use the following commandline

```
myapp.exe /runTest c:\myScript.cs
```

We could start to build our own Testing framework, wouldn't that be cool? ... er... no. It would be much less work if we could use an existing testing framework like nUnit, xUnit or MSTest from our application .

I guess I need to

- Start a UnitTestRunner
- Compile the Script
- tell the runner to run the tests in the compiled script assembly.

I have no idea where to start, because I have only used UnitTests from VisualStudio.

Would that be possible with any existing testing framework? Which are the main classes I would use?

Comment: You can create system tests with mstest/nunit/xunit. It's not just for unit tests. Just run them as you usually run unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Here a existing [answer how to run NUnit tests by yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798561/how-to-run-nunit-from-my-code).

Question is, what does you prevent from running the tests regularly?

To get to run myApp.exe c:\test\test.cs you would also need to compile the test, then run it. You still need to compile it against your app?

Can you debug your application from let's say Visual Studio? Right? So, you could add a 'sub project', which points to the main project for the dependencies and your code. Then you add your tests there, using NUnit regularly. 
Or what does prevent that?