# How to run NUnit tests from within C# code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a .NET Core NUnit Test project that contains a few `TestFixtures` with many `Tests`. I can run this project from within Visual Studio and I see test results in a special Visual Studio Test Results window.

Now, the thing is, I'd like to create a console application that would run these tests every 5 minutes and store the results of each test (did it succeed? How much time it was executing? If there were exceptions, what did they say? etc...). So, in pseudocode, I'd want to do something like:

```cs
var testsResults = RunTests("my NUnit test project from NuGet");
StoreResultsInDataBase(testResults);
```

How would I implement the `RunTests` method?
I found this post on SO: [How to run NUnit from my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798561/how-to-run-nunit-from-my-code)
One of the answers shows a code like this:

```cs
TestPackage package = new TestPackage(@"C:\YourProject.Tests.dll");
RemoteTestRunner remoteTestRunner = new RemoteTestRunner();
remoteTestRunner.Load(package);
TestResult result = remoteTestRunner.Run(new NullListener());
```

It seems to do exactly what I need. I tried using it, however, I had problems with the `TestPackage` class. I only found it in `NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework` package, which is a .NET Framework project from NuGet (I need to use .NET Core).

Is there a solution that would work with .NET Core?
The only solution I can think of is to use reflection to find all methods that have `[Test]` attribute and run them. However, it would be a bit problematic since my tests also use `[Order]` and need to be run in the correct order.

Comment: Why don't you use a CI tool that already does what you want and also generates fancy reports about tests?

Comment: @Eldar That's because running these tests is a part of my solution, not a part of CI/CD pipeline. The user (on UI) would enable/disable running tests of a specified environment. Enabling them would start up a container that would (on schedule) run the tests and store their results in the database. These results could be then displayed in a UI to see how a given environment is doing.

Comment: The sample code you found is for legacy NUnit V2, which won't help in .NET  Core.

Comment: @Charlie Do you know how the code should look like in V3?